# character (empty) replacement in R

Tags: r

I have been searching for a way to do this and coming to a dead end!

item1 is currently returning as character (empty) but I would like to find a way of saying if item1 returns as character (empty) then "0" otherwise display item1

Help and advice will be much appreciated!

Code

```
Goals <- PlayerScrape %>% 
  html_nodes("#yw1 tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(4)") %>%
  html_text()
  as.numeric()
```

Some Attempts

```
  Goals <- na.zero(Goals)
  if(is.null(Goals)){Goals <-0}
```

Other Attempts

```
Goals <- if(is.null(Goals)){0}else{Goals}

EmptyCheck <- nchar(as.character(Goals[1]))
```

Comment: where is your data, code, and your attempts

Comment: Have you tried something like ifelse(length(nchar(item1)) !=0 , item1, 0) ?

Comment: @JoelCarlson !!!!! YES!!! thank you!